# Datepicker not showing popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have used [jquery-ui date picker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) in my project.but its doesn't shows the popup..this is th code.please help me..

```
<tr>
    <td>Date of Submit<span class="red">*</span></td>
    <td height="48">:</td>
    <td height="48"><input type="text" id="dateof_sub" name="dateof_sub" class="normal">
    <span class="red" id="date_submit_error"></span></td>
</tr>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">

<script src="ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demos.css">
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dateof_sub" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You haven't included jQuery file

Comment: Do you get any javascript error ?

Comment: Thanks for Replaying Mr. Shaunak D .but still its not working..its working in other page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery referece, to have jQueryUI working - See **[jQueryUI](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui/info)**

These two references are enough - **[Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)**.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```